# How to search and extract strings in Unix?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I was trying to download data using Yahoo Finance with wget but ran into some issues with getting cookies and crumb. I used BTC-USD in this case and I saved the crumb data in a file named "crumbstore.txt".

```
wget --no-check-certificate --save-cookies=cookie.txt "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?p=BTC-USD" -O crumbstore.txt
```

From there I wanted to extract the crumb string and insert it into the quote link shown below ($crumb). The time period is from 2017-01-01 to 2020-01-06 in this case.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookie.txt "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BTC-USD?period1=1483265281&period2=1578305313&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=$crumb" -O BTC-USD_price.csv
```

In order to see how the "crumbstore.txt" file is structured, I ran the following code with grep.

```
grep -o ".\{0,50\}CrumbStore.\{0,50\}" crumbstore.txt
```

I was able to see what I needed to get was the series of letters and numbers stored in "CrumbStore":{"crumb":"**XXXXXXXXXXX**"}.

***Here is a snippet of crumbstore.txt and the essential task is to extract "BdpohsJbyt." from the text.***

```
"secondary_accounts":{"list":"Pos(r) M(0) P(0) List(n)","list_item":"Bdt(asMenuBorder)","anchor":"Td(n) Td(n):h Py(16px) D(b) Cf C(#000) Bgc(asMenuHoverBgc):h"}}}}},"CrumbStore":{"crumb":"BdpohsJbyt."},"StreamStore":{"articleCategory":{"term":"","label":""}
```

Comment: you can use python to get information from web page. BeautifulSoup is good library for your job. it will be better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to be JSON formatted, and unless you work in a very restrictive environment where dirty hacks are preferred over installing the right tools, you should just install `jq` (available in most distro repositories) and use that.

Without seeing the actual data, it's not possible to write down the correct jq invocation.

Answer (score 0):

How about deleting everything before and after the string, like

```
sed -n 's/^.*crumb":"//; s/".*$//p' crumb.store
XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not so clear for me what do you want to get or change. I grabbed the file on the way you did it, and extracted the string you may need from the crumbstore.txt file:

```
cat crumbstore.txt | grep -oE 'cru.\w*.:.{13}' | grep -Ev '{|pf'
```

which gave this result:

```
    crumb":"q7md5ctTst0"
    crumb":"WvBqKN8S0E5"
    crumb":"q7md5ctTst0"
    crumb":"q7md5ctTst0"
    crumb":"q7md5ctTst0"
```

And to extract the 11-char string from quotes I used awk

```
cat crumbstore.txt | grep -oE 'cru.\w*.:.{13}' | grep -Ev '{|pf' | awk -F'"' '{print $3}'
```

with this result:

```
    q7md5ctTst0
    WvBqKN8S0E5
    q7md5ctTst0
    q7md5ctTst0
    q7md5ctTst0
```

Is this what you whant?

Comment: Yes this looks awesome. Thank you!